# undefined method relative_url_root for nil:NilClass when running rspec on namespaced controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, rspec2

I'm working on a rails 2.3.18 to 3.2.x upgrade, and I've run into a problem with this one set of  controller tests:

Error:

```
/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:514:in `build_request_uri'
/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:470:in `process'
/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:49:in `process'
/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb:390:in `get'
# ./spec/controllers/integrations/formstack_controller_spec.rb:104:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

code triggering error:

```
it "should handle a failed access_token retreival" do
    FormStack::Oauth2Connection.any_instance.stub(:identify).and_return(nil)
    get "oauth_token"   # this line <---------------------------------------------------------------- 104
    response.should redirect_to(:controller => "/integrations/", :action => :index)
    flash[:error].should include("error")
end
```

the routes for this controller:

```
namespace :integrations, path: "/integrations" do
    match "formstack/oauth_token", :to => "formstack#oauth_token"
    resources :formstack
end
```

nothing special about my controller:

```
class Integrations::FormstackController < ApplicationController
    def oauth_token
       ...
    end
end
```

so what is it about

```
get "any_action_in_this_controller"
```

causes an this relative_url_root error? Every test for every action for this controller is bringing up the error.

what other information can I give that will help you guys help me debug this?

Comment: Same here, could you make it work? my controller is also namespaced...

Comment: Apparently a controller cannot have an action named config, renaming action solved the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by @marcario, if you have:

```
    def config
    end
```

in a controller, you will get this (obscure) error.  Just rename config to something else and the route mapping to match and you're good to go.

Comment: I discovered this myself a long time ago. Thanks for posting an answer! hopefully others won't be a frustrated as I was. ha

Comment: This is a weird one. Still works as of 26 Jul 2016. Thanks